# Django Migrations producing weird errors

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, django-models

I am trying to create a lottery app and it has been working fine but today when I tried to do a python manage.py migrate lotteryapp it started producing an error which stated

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'email'")
```

So I deleted all references of email to see if that would fix it but it still gives the error. I then deleted the database all together and started again but then it gave this error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I have gone in to my models.py file and gone back out and ran the command again and it gives the duplicate column error again. It doesn't make any sense. Here is my code from models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime

class Lottery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=50)
    date_drawn = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True)
    win_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    winning_numbers = models.IntegerField(default="")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Winner(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    winner_telephone = models.IntegerField(max_length=15, default="")
    lottery_numbers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lottery_won = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="") 
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    telephone = models.IntegerField(default="")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name

class entered_user(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    telephone = models.IntegerField(default="")
    lottery_numbers = models.IntegerField(default="")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

Comment: I've now removed the column email from the entered_user table in mysql (I don't know why or how it is in there) and I've ran the migration again and I now get the ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' error again. Also, whenever I do python manage.py makemigrations lotteryapp it adds an email column to the entered_user table in the database despite their being no reference to email in models.py

Comment: I have got it to a working state now, but I didn't find the cause of the problem. I had to completely delete the database and the entered_user model as well as deleting all the migrations and starting it again.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with fields `lottery_won` and `lottery_numbers`. Change the default to 0 and try again.

Comment: Did you changed winning_numbers, winner_telephone, telephone and related fields. The issue `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` occurs if we try to convert a string to integer. If there is any migration created remove and retry

Comment: I've fixed it now, I think there was a problem with my database and the migrations so I deleted both and started the database again. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

1. IntegerField can't have **default** string type and also has no attribute **max_length** :

   - winning_numbers = models.IntegerField(default="")
   - winner_telephone = models.IntegerField(max_length=15, default="")
   - telephone = models.IntegerField(default="")
   - lottery_numbers = models.IntegerField(default="")
2. Avoid calling your model User because it may cause conflict with the default django **User** Model and which may be the reason of email error message.

@CNB **I tried the code as follow I just changed The *User* to *UserModel* and the migration works fine:**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime

class Lottery(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=50)
   date_drawn = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True)
   win_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   winning_numbers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name

class Winner(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    winner_telephone = models.IntegerField(default="")
    lottery_numbers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lottery_won = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class UserModel(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    telephone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name

class entered_user(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    telephone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lottery_numbers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

Comment: I've now removed the default="" to be default=0 and User is now Lottery_User but I still have the same problem. It's very annoying because I run the migrate and get the invalid literal error and then I run it again and I get the duplicate column error. I don't have email anywhere in my models file so how is it adding it?!

Comment: As I mentioned, try to change the __User__ Model by __Profile__ or any other Name because I think it's making onflict with the django default User Model which has an email field.
Delete your database and try again.

Comment: I mentioned in the previous comment that I have done that and I've deleted the database too

Comment: check the snippet I just shared

Comment: I've fixed it now, I think there was a problem with my database and the migrations so I deleted both and started the database again. Thanks for your help